# Notation for Coordinate when $x$ is a certain number, max $y$

Tags: notation, coordinate-systems

I need your help for expression for mathematical notation.

There is a set of $(x,y)$ points. Among points satisfying $x$ is a certain number in the set, I want to express min $y$ value.

For example, points set $= \{(1,2), (2,4), (1,5),(1,8)\}$
Points satisfying '$x = 1$' are $(1,2),(1,5)$ and $(1,8)$. So min $y$ is $2$.

How can I express them as mathematical notation?
Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be your set then you could use either of

min {$y|(x,y)\in S,x=1$}

min {$y|(1,y)\in S$}.

You can put whatever conditions you want to the right of the | symbol.

Comment: S. Dolan, Thanks a lot!!